# Decipher "unbreakable" code

Tags: cipher

**I was sent this transcript on claims of being unbreakable. I am really not sure on how this is formatted so I have no idea where to start. Is it just a bunch of letters or is there something here? Please feel free to take a look:**

Daniel, transmit signal 013 via channel 22 dcs 103.

Transmission to be sent:

> V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509
>
> 83074 t624g b8053 jhx66 11195 642r3 h4d98 ui719 99310 yy333 83400 19495 628c9 b6295
>
> 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>
> 92644 92056 55329 08834 ccccc f85v5 9163l 92534 7qa6q
>
> 259 259 259
>
> Дышав хулам шаруют джаза защемят взгкаи вэнкм вьоес выгнать вожми выел тадж.
>
> 763 763 763
>
> Sierra Mike Oscar Oscar Juliet Charlie Alpha Zulu Mike Hotel Juliet
>
> 443 443 443
> *for coordinates*
>
> A2093
> C0816
> H3679
> T1058
> U6347
> N8520
> G3335
>
> C7254
> O6318
> D0000
> E4996
>
> 94331
>
> V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509 V509

**I am only learning ciphers so this is way past me.**

Comment: it says "ACHTUNG CODE" in the third and fourth last lines.

Comment: Do you think it means anything? Or just a coincidence. I searched it up and it came up with many different things.

Comment: in a message this short it's unlikely to be a coincidence

Comment: actually it says "ACHTUNG CODE 9"

Comment: Is this a puzzle you saw somewhere, or something that literally claims to be unbreakable? For a well constructed puzzle, the information provided therein should exhibit enough patterns to lead us on. Otherwise, [this](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) could be relevant. Anyway, the 111... line looks like [base-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system), you can translate the Russian to get some junk and English words and the Sierra Mike line is the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system).

Comment: @Reti43 - it's not Russian. It's just garbage words using Cyrillic.

Comment: @RadoslavHristov I'm thinking this is just a bunch of random crap and there's nothing here

Comment: Some words are indeed from Russian language, although they make no sense in combination. If starting from 1, then words 1,4,5,9,11 are real Russian words. 2,3 and the last — maybe. Others are obviously garbage.

Comment: According to Google Translate, the string of Russian means, "Breathe hulam sharuyut jazz jam ESSACA Banks weight expel Squeeze vyel Taj." Part of it seems to be nonsense.

Comment: @mestackoverflow Do you realy think using Google Translator will "decode" something for you or to find something will meaningful in a ciphered text? Nope, Nope, Nope...

Comment: No, I don't ....

Comment: It could be some kind of chatlog. Code 9 is often used in chats. "Achtung" is a German word for danger/attention

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer
Some of the numbers looked like zip codes to me (especially the 92000s, so this is what I found out)

> 92644; 92056; 55329 are zip codes in the respective order:
>
>  92644: Garden Grove, California, United States of America
>
>  92056: Oceanside/San Diego, California, United States of America
>
>  55329: Eden Valley, Minnesota.

>

> The Russian stuff translates to this from Google translate: "Breathing blasphemers jazz jazz will be hindered and vengeance vyoes vygnat vozhmi ate a Taj."